# Get SharedPreference between two Activitys

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have troubles reading my SharedPreference from ContactView.Java in my MainActivity.Java

This is what i have in my ContactView.Java:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("contactName", name);
        editor.putString("contactPhone", phoneNo);
        editor.commit();
```

and this in my OnCreate for setting them to the TextViews:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = settings.getString("contactName", "");
    //the second parameter set a default data if “contactName” is empty
    if (!name.isEmpty()){
        textView1.setText(name);
    }
    String phoneNo = settings.getString("contactPhone", "");//the second parameter set a default data if “contactName” is empty
    if (!phoneNo.isEmpty()){
        textView2.setText(phoneNo);
    }
```

Now when i go to MainActivity i would like to read them:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String phoneNo =  sharedPreferences.getString("contactPhone", "");
String name =  sharedPreferences.getString("contactName", "");
```

But the Strings seem to be empty and not contain any name or phoneNo what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can check: http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html

The reason is:
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences != getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);

My suggestion is use singleton context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057273/android-singleton-with-global-context
Then from this context you can get sharedPref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MainActivity you're supposed to use the same preference file:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);
String phoneNo =  settings.getString("contactPhone", "");
String name =  settings.getString("contactName", "");
```

Comment: When u say SharedPreferences settings you need to say settings.getString am i right?

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing 2 different SharedPreferences files.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

is different than

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Use

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In two activity A and B you can use shared preferences in this following manner.

in activity A you can create a shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("contactName", name);
        editor.putString("contactPhone", phoneNo);
        editor.commit();
```

In activity B you can use the shared prefrences with same name

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SelectedContact", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String phoneNo =  settings .getString("contactPhone", "");
String name =  settings .getString("contactName", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You can create custom class for adding, retrieving, checking and deleting data in SharedPreference very easily.

```
public class Pref_Storage {
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    public static void openPref(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void deleteKey(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        boolean b = result.containsKey(key);
        if (b) {
            Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.remove(key);

            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
            prefsPrivateEditor = null;
            Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences = null;
        }
    }

    public static void setDetail(Context context, String key, String value) {
        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, value);

        prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
        prefsPrivateEditor = null;
        Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences = null;
    }

    public static Boolean checkDetail(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        boolean b = result.containsKey(key);
        return b;
    }

    public static String getDetail(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        String b = result.get(key);
        return b;

    }
}
```

For set data:

```
Pref_Storage.setDetail(context, "contactName", name);
Pref_Storage.setDetail(context, "phoneNo", phoneNo);
```

For retrieving data:

```
Pref_Storage.getDetail(context, "contactName");
Pref_Storage.getDetail(context, "phoneNo");
```

For checking data:

```
Pref_Storage.checkDetail(context, "contactName");
Pref_Storage.checkDetail(context, "phoneNo");
```

For deleting data:

```
Pref_Storage.deleteKey(context, "contactName");
Pref_Storage.deleteKey(context, "phoneNo");
```