# Why SQLite handling has to happen on activity or service class?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am looking for a way to `openOrCreateDatabase` from another non-activity class and all tutorials and SO questions I found so far, are against that.

Why?

Method `openOrCreateDatabase` can be called only from Service or Activity or I can call it as a static method `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase`.

However, this method's second parameter, requires `CursorFactory`, which in most tutorials is: `MODE_PRIVATE`. I can't use `MODE_PRIVATE` from a non-activity class. Some suggest to use `context.MODE_PRIVATE`, but I wanted to avoid such dependency of passing a `context` from every activity that I want to use the DB.

What is the best way to have only one DB connection and DB handling in one class across all activities?

Comment: MODE_PRIVATE is a static final field

Comment: How would you access it then?

Comment: like any static field: `ClassName.STATIC_FIELD`

Comment: what doesn;t work? see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: If I do this: SQLiteHandler.MODE_PRIVATE it says it is undefined...

Comment: Anyway maybe you understood my question wrong, I was asking what is the right way to access database from a centralized data layer...

Comment: It isn't defined... it's a context variable I guess.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()` requires `String path` / `File file` and `SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory`, there is no `int` parameter like `MODE_*`

Comment: Just take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example the first code paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you access your `SQLiteDatabase` through a [singleton](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html)?

```
private static DatabaseHelper sInstance = null;

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
 }

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

If so, then the above still requires a `Context` argument, but if you're averse to passing one around then you can use this [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057273/android-singleton-with-global-context):

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App instance;

    public static App get() { 
        return instance; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

So you could access your database with `DatabaseHelper.getInstance(App.get());`

Comment: That is what I decided to use few minutes ago, great, thank you :)