# ResourcesNotFoundException when trying to load a resource

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-resources

I get

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060000
```

when I try to load a bitmap from a resource in my res/drawable folder (even intelliJ auto-complete finds them) like so:

```
public Sprite(int resource, int numberOfFrames){
    BitmapRegionDecoder spriteSheet = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(+resource);
        spriteSheet = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);
    } catch (IOException ioexc){
        ioexc.printStackTrace();
    }
    timer = 0;
    this.numberOfFrames = numberOfFrames;
    frames = new Bitmap[numberOfFrames];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++) {
        frames[i] = spriteSheet.decodeRegion(new Rect(i*32, 0, (i*32)+32, 32), null);
    }
```

and I pass the resource only 2 times:

```
public class PlayerSprite extends Sprite {
    private boolean isHitting;
    private int timer;

    public PlayerSprite() {
        super(R.drawable.player_sprite_sheet, 3);
        timer = 0;
    }

 //...more core...//

}
```

and here:

```
sprite = new Sprite(R.drawable.ball_sprite, 7);
```

Here you can see my [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kvj8.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Resources.getSystem()` is the problem in your case. It returns a  global shared Resources object but not the one of the application. You should use `Context.getResource()` instead, which returns

> a resources instance for the application's package

here you can find the documentation for [Context.getResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) and for [Resources.getSystem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem())

Comment: hmm, I get an error saying Context doesn't have getResource() method, do I need to pass a context by a constructor or something?

Comment: yes you have to. If you are subclassing view, you can use `getContext()`

Comment: ohh this is bad, I will have to pass it through several constructors at best, do I need to get the context from my view class, since my view class isn't connected to my sprite classes. Also I am converting my java swing app to android, so i am not very familiar with android.

Comment: probably the Application's context for this use case is enough. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057273/android-singleton-with-global-context)