# How to retrieve a list of data from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am trying to retrieve data from sharedPreferences:

```
    public static void loadArray(Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    WorkList.clear();
    int size = mSharedPreference1.getInt("Status_size", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        WorkList.add(mSharedPreference1.getString("Status_" + i, null));
    }
}
```

i got this code but don't know how to call this method. I try to call this method in the same non-activity class.

Comment: try : `YourClassName.loadArray(getContext());`

Comment: I tried and it said: " Non-static method 'loadArray(android.content.Context) cannot be referenced from a static context "
the code i tried:

public void main(String[] args)
{
    MainActivity.loadArray(getApplicationContext());
}

Comment: He said its a non activity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an app Singleton Class by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057777/2555419) link

Then you can call the method by `loadArray(AppSingleton.getInstance().getContext())`

Once you are a bit comfortable and have understood the concept switch to using `Dagger2` to handle singletons

Comment: your link is dead

Comment: I changed it. This may seem intimidating for a new developer, but its a really safe option. A bad way of just getting it done may be using a public static context from an activity,but seriously DONT!