# Instance variable in a Singleton class accessed by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, singleton

I have a singleton class:

```
public class School {
    private HashMap<String, String> students;

    private static School school;

    private School(){
        students = new HashMap<String, String>();   
    }

    public static School getInstance(){
       if(school == null){
           school = new School();
       }
       return school;
    }

    //Method to add student
    protected void addStudent(String id, String name){
          students.put(id,name);
    }
    //Method to remove student
    protected void removeStudent(String id){
          students.remove(id);
    }
}
```

As you can see above, in the singleton class, I have a `students` variable (a `HashMap`), there are methods to add & remove student in the class.

In my application, there could be multiple threads using this `School` class to `getInstance()` , then adding & removing student. To make the access (**especially the access to** `students` **instance**) be **thread safe**, I am thinking to use `synchorized` keyword for `getInstanc()` method, like:

```
public synchronized static School getInstance(){
       if(school == null){
           school = new School();
       }
       return school;
    }
```

But I think my trivial change only can make sure only **one** `School` instance be created in multi-thread environment. What else do I need to do in order to make it **thread safe  for accessing the** `students` **instance by multiple threads as well**. Any good suggestion or comment is appreicated, thanks!

Comment: Read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165852/java-singleton-and-synchronization

Comment: Is lazy initialization a requirement?

Comment: Yes, lazy initialization is a requirement

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: Does ConcurrentHashMap help ? It looks like that is what you need. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Why, @kocko & chrylis you think my question is duplicated with your links. It is NOT. My question is focusing on the HashMap students variable, not about how to make sure only one School instance is created in multi-thread environment. Please check my question carefully.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this question. Actually even I am trying to do something similar on the `Map` if you can provide the sample code that worked for you then it would be really helpful for me as I am pretty new to Java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving the conversation on whether singletons are evil or not, let's consider only the thread safety issues in your `School` class:

- **The shared object is created "lazily"** - this needs synchronization to avoid making two instances of `School`; you have correctly identified and fixed this issue. However, since initializing `School` does not take much time, you might as well make `getInstance()` a trivial getter by initializing `school = new School()` eagerly.
- **The hash map inside the School** - concurrent access to the hash map will result in exceptions. You need to add synchronization around the code that adds, removes, and iterates students to avoid these exceptions.
- **Access to individual students** - once the callers get a `Student` object, they may start modifying it concurrently. Therefore the `Student` object needs concurrency protection of their own.

Comment: Hi, for individual student, each thread only need to access the getter method(e.g. getStudentName()), is your 3rd point still an issue?

Comment: @Mellon If your threads only get `Student`s' properties, but not set them, then you do not need synchronization there.

Answer (score 0):

The HashMap implementation is not thread-safe, so bad things may happen if several thread operate on it at the same time. A quick fix is [making the map itself synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29):

```
    students = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

Note that if you iterate on this map, the iteration also has to be made in a `synchronized` block; otherwise other threads may modify the map while you are iterating.

A thread-safe alternative to `HashMap` is [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing method makes them thread safe it means only one thread can execute that method at a time.

However, in above situation, i would suggest to synchronized addStudent and removeStudent method only. Or you can synchronized students hash map also using -

Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or a [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

[This](http://www.seegler.in/blogs/tech/entry/hashmap_vs_concurrenthashmap_vs_synchronized) article gives a good explanation