# can someone help me with my global variables?

Tags: android, singleton

Ok, I am creating a program that uses a normal global class
but it doesn't seam to work. I can get the value of variables from the global but I cant set a new value.

I created a really short test program just to get this to work so I can change it to my other much bigger program.

In this small program I have a textview and a edit text with a button in the middle

all it is designed to do is when the button is clicked take what was typed in the editText and place it in a variable and send that variable to globals

then at the same time get the variable from globals and  set the textView text to that variable...EASY...

but it will not save to globals...

can someone help me please?

here is the global code that I am using.

```
 package com.example.arnoldray007.globalstest;

    /**
     * Created by arnoldray007 on 5/3/2016.
     */
    public class Globals
    {
        private static Globals instance;

        //this is the global variable
        private String received;

        //this restricts the constructor from being instantiated
        private Globals(){}

        public void setReceived(String r)
        {
            this.received = r;
        }

        public String getReceived()
        {
            return this.received;
        }


        //this is the global variable
        private String send = "Sorry im busy right now.";

        public void setSend(String s)
        {
            this.send = s;
        }

        public String getSend()
        {
            return this.send;
        }
      public static synchronized Globals getInstance()
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Globals();
            }
            return instance;
        }
```

and here is the MainActivity code that I am using

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
    String received = g.getReceived();  //this retrieves the variable


    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    String temp;

    public void myClickThree(View v)//this is my onclickThree for my refresh button
    {
        temp = editText.getText().toString();
        g.setReceived(temp); //this sends the new  message to the global variable adding it to it
        received = g.getReceived();
        editText.setText(received);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help that I can get......

I am getting an error now can anyone tell me what this means?

```
05-05 09:41:47.476 9601-9601/com.example.arnoldray007.arnoldfinalproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arnoldray007.arnoldfinalproject/com.example.arnoldray007.arnoldfinalproject.Received_messages}: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:3118)
      at com.example.arnoldray007.arnoldfinalproject.Received_messages.onCreate(Received_messages.java:91)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: a typo *test not text

Comment: I suppose I could help you by telling you global variables are, generally, a terrible idea.

Comment: this is a test program lol will not be used, only to figure out how to change the value of my global variable

Comment: BUt, I have a receiver and  inorder to take a variable from that and use it on another class I need a global

Comment: the receiver gets all messages that are sent to me by text and I want to store those messages so I can display them on a different screen and in order to do that I need to send that variable to a different class. and the only way I know how to do that is by Intent or global variables

Comment: can you please add the getInstance() method implementation?

Comment: I have until Tuesday to get this program running lol

Comment: Globals g = Globals.getInstance();

Comment: at the top of main activity

Comment: I can get  the variables from the globals but it will not save new values to globals

Comment: added a answer to better explain: a wrong getinstance() implementation could cause the problem

Comment: I have spent days on this and a few other problems, I haven't taken a Java class, and im teaching myself everything. its slow going and android studio always  has problems....

Comment: I added what I am using at the bottom of globals code

Comment: Suggestion, move the declaration of `String temp` to the body of `myClickThree()`. The way it's coded now, `temp` is acting like a global variable of `MainActivity ` (a Bad Thing).

Comment: if someone has a better idea on how to take a variable and send it to another class without a intent  im up for that idea as well

Comment: yea , I had it their and it didn't work so I movend it to see if it changed anything

Comment: I think that this part of the code may be wrong(g.setReceived(temp);)????

Comment: because when the button returns the variable it returns a null value(empty) that means that the global value was never changed...

Comment: anyone have a idea why my code wont work?

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? You take some string out of an EditText, but you put it back in the same EditText.... Anyways, options: 1) Use an Intent because why not? 2) Use SharedPreferences if you plan on saving that data in the long-term.

Comment: I take data out of the editText and place it in a global variable and then get that variable back and place that text in a textView

Comment: its for a messageing system

Comment: the receiver only runs when I get a text, it has no intent in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with the code you've shown except your comment seems misleading.

> this sends the new  message to the global variable adding it to it

Nothing is being added to anything. Because your method there only does an assignment.

```
public void setReceived(String r)
{
    this.received = r;
}
```

If you want to see that your class is actually working, maybe you should do something more than get text from an EditText and assign the string back into the EditText. That will only *appear* like nothing is happening.

So, try this instead in `onCreate()`

```
g = Globals.getInstance();

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String temp = editText.getText().toString();
        g.setReceived(temp);
        received = g.getReceived();
        textView.append("\n"+received);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great on my test application, but  when I try to implement it on my real application it pops up with an error

Comment: The error `java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.TextView.append` means you didn't initialize your TextView or findViewById returned null

Comment: I don't understand , because I did. here is what I have for the display( EditText editText9, changeEditText;)---(changeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.changeEditText);)---rember that I said that the error was coming from my real program not the test program..... the test program works fine with the answer below... but when I ad the fix to my program it gives me this error...

Comment: That's an EditText, not a Textview. Anyways. I'm not sure why you'd get an error in one device, but not another. I'm just telling you what the error means

Answer (score 1):

in singleton pattern getInstance() should be:

```
private static Globals instance;

public static Globals getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new Globals();
    return instance;
}
```

Are you sure to have this exact code inside Globals class body?

EDIT:

I think for this kind of problem the best solution is using a superclass Application, where you mantain all the global stuffs. You will find thousands of tutorial on this android programming pattern, just google "extending application android".

Comment: That MAY be the problem. If you're creating the instance every time you call getInstance(), it will look like the object is not saving the new values.

Comment: did you look at what im using

Comment: its the same but inbetween Globals and Static I have Synchronized

Comment: public static synchronized Globals getInstance()
            {
                if(instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Globals();
                }
                return instance;
            }

Comment: I saw it after you added it. It looks like you added it after my comment.

Comment: but, I still cant change the value of the variable in the global class using the button

Comment: that's what I was talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165852/java-singleton-and-synchronization.  I'll probably use synchronized in getReceived and setReceived methods, but it depends on what you want to do

Comment: if your talking about a class that Extends application, then change the name of the program to the name of your class, I tried that as well