# Is my code thread safe already

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a singleton class:

```
public class MySingleton {
  private static MySingleton instance;

  // here the Map entry's value is also a Map
  private Map<String, Map> dataMap;

  private MySingleton() {
     dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();

     Map<String, String> dataTypeOneMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
     Map<String, String> dataTypeTwoMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

     dataMap.put("dataTypeOne", dataTypeOneMap);
     dataMap.put("dataTypeTwo", dataTypeTwoMap);

  }

  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
     if(instance == null) {
        instance = new MySingleton();
     }
     return instance;    
  }

  public synchronized void storeData(String data, String type) {
       dataMap.get(type).put("my_data", data);
  } 

  public synchronized String getData(type) {
       return dataMap.get(type).get("my_data");
  } 
}
```

Multiple threads can access the public methods `storeData(...)` & `getData(...)`. e.g.:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().storeData("hello", "dataTypeOne");

MySingleton.getInstance().getData("dataTypeOne");
```

Do I need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` type for `dataMap`? or is it already thread safe? I feel my code is already thread safe but just want to make sure no corner case would break it. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165852/java-singleton-and-synchronization

Comment: Does it really have to be lazy? *That* part is not thread safe.

Comment: @Fildor, could you please share more details what is in your mind? Thanks.

Comment: Apart from Question: Mind that you get a NPE in storeData if value of `type` is not in map.

Comment: Think of 2 threads calling `getInstance()` for the first time: both could get different instances because at the time of calling `instance` is null and you'd then lose data if one thread calls `storeData()` on an instance that's overwritten by the other.

Comment: Not sure about your requirements. But the code above is threadsafe..multiple invocations of storeData thr diff threads will not tamper your HashMap

Comment: @Jai No it's not threadsafe. It's a common boobytrap to implement the lazy instantiation not thread safe. So two instances could actually be created!

Comment: @Thomas would synchronizing `getInstance` fix that?

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments the lazy instantiation of the instance is not threadsafe, i.e. if 2 threads call `getInstance()` simultaneously both calls could result in `instance = new MySingleton();` and even return a different `instance` which would mean both threads operate on different objects.

To fix that you could synchronize `getInstance()` on the class itself and even use double-checked locking to reduce synchronization overhead (if you can't remove the lazyness in the first place):

```
private volatile MySingleton  instance;

public static MySingleton getInstance() {
  //check if the instance doesn't exist yet, this is not threadsafe
  if(instance == null) {
    //the instance doesn't exist yet so synchronize and check again, since another thread 
    // might have entered this block in the meantime and instance is not null anymore
    synchronized(MySingleton.class) {
      if(instance == null) {
        instance = new MySingleton();
      }
    }
  }
  return instance;    
}
```

Using double-checked locking you'd be able to only synchronize the creation part, checking for null and returning the instance if it isn't null doesn't have to be threadsafe.

Comment: Does `instance` still has to be volatile in Java 8?

Comment: Complicated stuff :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Comment: @Fildor ah, I'm not entirely sure but according to [this Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) "reads and writes are atomic for reference variables " so I'd say no. - Update: as per the wiki article linked by Jack volatile might still be useful to prevent errors due to reordering by the compiler. And adding `volatile` shouldn't hurt anyways.

Comment: @Thomas, so, as a conclusion, there is no need to use ConcurrentHashMap for `dataMap`, right? Only the lazy initialization is a issue to fix? And using `volatile` is nice to have for the `instance` variable, am I all right?

Comment: @Leem.fin have a look at the wiki article linked by Jack. I'd include `volatile` to be sure. As for the maps: you'd not need a `ConcurrentHashMap` if you synchronize all methods that access the maps but removing that synchronization and using `ConcurrentHashMap` instead could improve performance, since it uses (mostly) lock-free algorithms (i.e. writes/reads on different buckets often don't need to be synchronized at all).

Comment: @Fildor Volatile will ensure the integrity regarding the fact that you always get the actual reference rather than any cache. I will definitely add that.

Comment: You don't actually need `volatile` in this example to be thread safe, because you have the `synchronized` keyword around all access to the `instance` variable. It will however give marginally better performance in calls to `getInstance()` when first checking `if(instance == null)` to prevent it from entering the inner `synchronized(MySingleton.class)` unnecessarily

Comment: I prefer the holder pattern anyway but I conclude, I would make it volatile just to be on the safe side ...

Comment: @Leem.fin this answer seems legit. you should accept it

Comment: Actually, this double-check pattern isn't recommended. See the Brian Goetz Concurrency book, p.348 - the recommended way is to use an inner resource holder class for lazy initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**:

This portion of your code is not thread-safe:

```
  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
      instance = new MySingleton();
    }
    return instance;    
  }
```

**Long answer**

Let's tackle the code portions one by one.

For instance, assume that one thread is executing **getInstance** method and reached to if condition:

```
if(instance == null) {
```

Now if another thread starts to call the method, the if condition will still be true and it will also try to create a new instance. So it may create some use cases:

1. Two calling method will end up with the different instance.
2. Later thread overrides the instance of the previously created instance or vice versa.

**Solution:**

Synchronize the instance creation block:

```
synchronized(MySingleton.class){
  if(instance == null) {
    instance = new MySingleton();
  }
}
```

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: how are they fixed? That's how you answer a question.

Comment: Could you please explain more than "it is not thread safe", thanks.

Comment: Note that `this` isn't available in a static method. You need another lock monitor, e.g. the class itself.

Comment: @Thomas, good catch mate. Missed that. Updating answer with the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not thread safe.  Use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to allow access and modification from different threads. It'll also allow you to read from the Map asynchronously without performance hits.

Synchronize the getInstance() method, and minimize the amount of calls to that method - storing a reference to the singleton on each object running on another thread to keep from repeated getInstance() calls will help.

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't fix the issue with `getInstance()` not being threadsafe

Comment: But it is a singleton, and public method already used `synchronized` keyword, why it is not thread safe? Could you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Because `private static MySingleton instance;` can be reassigned multiple times with multiple calls to `getInstance()` as this method is not synchronized

Comment: @Brad only if he's not storing an instance to the object on each thread

Comment: @Brad how can MySingleton be reassigned? Isn't the purpose of a singleton to keep that very thing from happening?

Comment: @Leem.fin edited my answer to account for getInstance()

Answer (score 0):

1. Thread safe Singleton

   You can define thread safe LazySingleton by following this post:

   [Why is volatile used in this example of double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking/36099644#36099644)
2. Your `dataMap` is thread safe. But you can further optimize your code. You can replace `Map` with `ConcurrentHashMap` and remove `synchronized` in both `storeData` and `getData` methods.

You can have a look at this documentation page regarding [high level concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)