# Singleton design pattern java idioma

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, idioms

I'm quite confused. I found many implementations of the Singleton Design Pattern in java. One of the implementations I found is the following:

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static class Loader {
        static MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
    }

    private MySingleton () {}

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return Loader.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

as explained here: [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11165975).
Now, if this implementation should work, why doesn't the following?

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton () {}

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I searched around how java handles initializations, but couldn't find anything showing the latter code will not work.
Instead, I found the following: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3499322), which points out that every static initialization happen before a static method of the class is invoked, so the static field holding the singleton instance should be initialized when the only method accessing INSTANCE (getInstance) is invoked.
So yes, i'm really confused: if this code works, why not using this simpler version of the singleton design pattern?

Comment: The latter does work: it is an *eager* singleton, whereas the former is a *lazy* singleton.

Answer (score 5):

The both work and are valid implementation of the singleton.
The first one uses a lazy initialization.
It means that the singleton is created only as `getInstance()` is invoked by a client.
The second one uses an eager initialization.
It means that the singleton is created as soon as the `MySingleton` class is loaded by the classloader.

In practice, it doesn't make a big difference because generally `getInstance()` and the singleton class loading are often coupled.
It is indeed rare to have a client class that refers to a singleton class without requesting its instance via `getInstance()`.

So, in the general case, the second way (eager initialization) that is more concise should be favored.

Comment: What about concerns about being able to create additional instances of the class via reflection?

Comment: @nasukkin Neither way addresses that concern, so it is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @nasukkin Many things may be changed by reflection. Fields without mutators,  fields with `final` modifiers, etc... If you provide a component to clients and that you need/want to protect class definitions and object states, using an enum for singleton is fine but it would be certainly not enough. As public components is clearly not the matter, referencing this concern would bring more confusion than other thing.

Answer (score 1):

Java's built-in implementation of the singleton pattern is `enum`. When you define an `enum`, you declare and initialize (aka "enumerate") all of the instances that can ever possibly exist in the runtime. The approach provided in your original question has vulnerabilities; a clever user **can** create new, unmanaged instances of your "singleton" class. (I'd recommend reading Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" book for his examples on how this can be accomplished.)

You should consider implementing your singleton like so:

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE();

    /* delcare instance fields here. */

    /** constructor; give it params if you need to. */
    public MySingleton() {
        // initialize whatever you need here.
    }

    /* methods you'll use go here. */
}
```

When you need your singleton, you would simply reference it as `MySingleton.INSTANCE`.

Comment: Syntax error: *Illegal modifier for the enum constructor; only private is permitted.*

Comment: @Andreas you get Syntax error because you define an enum writing INSTANCE; (without the brackets)

Comment: @taran95 No, I get syntax error because the constructor is `public`, and only `private` is allowed, *exactly like the error says*.

Comment: To be exact, `package-private` (default access modifier) and `private` are allowed.