# Singleton class in Android application using synchronized initalizer

Tags: java, android, performance, thread-safety, singleton

I need a single instance of one class to be used across my whole Android application.
I am using the following code to achieve this and I want to be sure that doing it like this is correct, thread-safe and doesn't have an impact on performance.

```
    public class MyClass {

        private static MyClass instance;

        public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() {
            MyClass myClass;
            synchronized (MyClass.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new MyClass();
                }
                myClass = instance;
            }
            return myClass;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I need an instance of MyClass in the application, I call:

```
MyClass.getInstance();
```

So, I want ot be sure I'm not doing something wrong here, that this approach won't cause any problems down the line of development and if there are any better alternatives.

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165852/java-singleton-and-synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need a second `synchronized` inside `getInstance` method and also you need to make `MyClass` constructor to be private.

```java
public class Singleton  {
 
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;
 
    // other instance variables can be here
     
    private Singleton() {};
 
    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Second `synchronized` functions as a lock for the time the class instance is being created. I was not quite sure if whole method synchronization is enough and therefore used it. Also, should I add `volatile` property to the `INSTANCE` variable or is that pointless?

Comment: pointless, the first `synchronized` is enough