# Why is Java's switch enum so painfully slow on the first run compared to its 'if' equivalent?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, enums, switch-statement

Why is Java's switch enum so painfully slow on the first run compared to its 'if' equivalent?

I'm aware that the JVM needs to "warm-up" before performance can be reliably measured. Therefore every first call is much much slower than any subsequent one. This does not mean we cannot measure the performance based on every first run.

The criteria for the test are:

1. Always perform a fresh run.
2. Measure time in nanoseconds to execute a single function which always returns an integer based on passed value evaluated either by `if` statements or a `switch` statement.
3. Store returned value and print it in the end, so it doesn't get discarded in the process.

I tested enums first and expected a slight difference in performance.

Instead I got an average of:

- `77596` nanoseconds - on if
- `585232` nanoseconds - on switch

I wanted to see if only enums have this unfavorable property, so I also tested it with integers and strings (since Java 7 it is possible to use strings in switch statements)

*INTS*:

- `2308` nanoseconds - on if
- `1950` nanoseconds - on switch

*STRINGS*:

- `8517` nanoseconds - on if
- `8322` nanoseconds - on switch

Both these tests yield very similar results, suggesting that if and switch statements are equivalent, very similar or equally good on every run, however this is not the case with enums.

I tested this both on Windows and Linux with both Java 8 and Java 17.

Here is the switch enum code:

```java
public class SwitchEnum{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long st = System.nanoTime();
        int val = getValue(Day.FRIDAY);
        long en = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("SwitchEnum perf nano: " + (en - st));
        System.out.println("Sum: " + val);
    }

    public static int getValue(Day day){
        switch (day){
            case MONDAY:
                return 7;
            case TUESDAY:
                return 3;
            case WEDNESDAY:
                return 5;
            case THURSDAY:
                return 2;
            case FRIDAY:
                return 1;
            case SATURDAY:
                return 6;
            case SUNDAY:
                return 4;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the if enum code:

```java
public class IfEnum{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long st = System.nanoTime();
        int val = getValue(Day.FRIDAY);
        long en = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("IfEnum perf nano: " + (en - st));
        System.out.println("Sum: " + val);
    }

    public static int getValue(Day day){
        if (day == Day.MONDAY){
            return 7;
        }else if (day == Day.TUESDAY){
            return 3;
        }else if (day == Day.WEDNESDAY){
            return 5;
        }else if (day == Day.THURSDAY){
            return 2;
        }else if (day == Day.FRIDAY){
            return 1;
        }else if (day == Day.SATURDAY){
            return 6;
        }else if (day == Day.SUNDAY){
            return 4;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

And the enum:

```java
public enum Day{
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;
}
```

I also tested this in C and C# to see if switch statements on enums have a significant performance drawback compared to its if equivalents - there was none. I've also noticed that if we provide an instruction in 'default' or equivalent 'else' the performance also increases so I included it in all tests.

This question is not about the typical "if vs switch" battle, but rather what's going on with enums and switch statements.

In any case why should the switch with enums be on average 7 times slower than it's equivalent? What could be the cause of this?

It seems like I have been misunderstood. In truth the original enum was completely different, as I was trying to find the culprit of the 'unreasonable overhead' I came up with this benchmark.

Funnily enough, warming up the JVM doesn't help the performance of that function at all.

You can put some nested loops before the method in question:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
                System.out.println(j);
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        long st = System.nanoTime();
        int val = getValue(Day.FRIDAY);
        long en = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("SwitchEnum perf nano: " + (en - st));
        System.out.println("Sum: " + val);
    }
```

The only thing that matters is if it was already called. Every subsequent call is optimized. Whether it's a constructor, function or an object's method. The fact is that if you're initializing a framework you will only call the 'initialize()' method once (which will in turn call other methods on its way). In this particular case the only thing you'd care about is the performance of the first invocation of a function. Let's suppose that your framework calls 8000 methods when it's first launched. Each method takes 1ms to execute, so it propagates to 8 seconds on every run. And the Java community is simply going to say "you're benchmarking it incorrectly"? No. This is how long it takes to get that particular framework up and running. Naturally performance is lost here and there. You can always make it faster and better. There is no reason for the switch enum statement to add **0.6ms** to the clock given that its 'if' equivalent takes **0.1ms**.

So here I am asking, what is the source of this overhead?

Comment: You are executing each method once. This is not how you benchmark Java code. The JIT will not have a chance to optimize a single call.

Comment: I am aware that JIT will not optimize a single call. The question strictly and specifically pertains to the switch enum and why was it 7 times slower than its 'if' equivalent.

Comment: Take default: out of the switch and put it in an if else after the switch use default on one of the other day if you must put it there. See what the result is then. Technically with the if else version the new runtimeecxeption does not get setup for any possible evaluation with the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have a symbolic reference like `case FRIDAY:`, you expect it to be executed for the enum constant `FRIDAY`, regardless of the other constants in that class or, in other words, to keep working even if constants were added or removed before it or the declaration order changed.

This is mandated by [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.26):

> Adding or reordering enum constants in an enum class will not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

The specification does not tell how compilers should achieve this and there are interesting differences between the existing compilers.

Both compilers, `javac` and `ecj`, will generate code for creating an `int[]` array, mapping the enum’s runtime [ordinal numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) to the numbers used in the compiled bytecode (as bytecode instructions only switch over `int` values). Since both compilers generate the code in a way that the array is created the first time, the `switch` statement is executed, and then reused, this is a common cause for a higher first-time execution overhead.

When you look at the `javac` compiled code, you’ll notice another class file, like `SwitchEnum$1.class`, alongside your class. This class will hold the mentioned array, created in the class initializer. This follows [a known pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11165975/2711488) for having a thread safe lazy initialization without the need for synchronization primitives for subsequent accesses. But of course, it adds to the first time initialization overhead. In the worst case, depending on the JVM, you have the costs of loading, verifying, and initializing the second class right at the first execution of the `switch` statement.

Eclipse, on the other hand, adds a `private static volatile` field to the class containing the `switch` statement and will initialize it lazily based on a `null` test. So there is not the initialization overhead of a second class, but a `volatile` write, which might be faster in the first execution. But this code will pay the price of a `volatile` read every time, the `switch` statement is subsequently executed. Though, we should be thankful for the `volatile` read, as for more than a decade, [eclipse just produced code that was not thread safe](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544521), with low chances of identifying the problem if you ever stumbled over this, as there’s no mutable state visible in the source code.

Even after the initialization, there can be a performance penalty due to the fact that the code depends on the contents of an `int[]` array created at runtime, hence, is less predictable than the sequence of `if` statements. This depends on the surrounding code and usually doesn’t matter. But the JDK developers stumbled across this issue at least once themselves and created [this ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8282722). The report contains a link to the scenario where it happened to be truly performance relevant.

There’s [a discussion to use `invokedynamic` for `switch`](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/compiler-dev/2023-January/021663.html) in the future, which would not change the first time overhead, but improve the subsequent executions, as after linking, the code will be entirely predictable for the JIT, especially for the 99% of all cases where the mapping would be an identity function.

One improvement has been made to JDK 21’s `javac`: it will not use this array indirection when the `switch` statement is within the enum type itself, as in this case, the constants can’t get reordered without recompiling the `switch` statement. This is also fixing [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7176515).

Note that the array is shared between all `switch` statements over the same enum type within one class, so even if one statement is executed only once, other statements may still benefit from the already initialized array. If there truly is only one `switch` statement in this class, executed at most once, e.g. in a class initializer, and initialization time matters that much, or you truly experience a performance bottleneck at one specific `switch` statement, you may resort to [Elliott Frisch’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75817776/2711488) and put the intended value into the enum type itself (if you have the option to change the enum type). Otherwise, you may use `if` statements at that specific place.

For code executed more than once, an `EnumMap` may also help if you can’t modify the enum type itself.

Comment: Nice one! Some very interesting information there.

Comment: Some very deep rabbit hole we fell down.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't giving the JIT time to optimize the call, you don't benchmark Java code by calling a method once in isolation; that won't give you a meaningful result. Also, your approach of switching on an `enum` or using an `if` to determine a mapped value is flawed. Store the value with the `enum` itself and call that directly.  Like,

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY(7), TUESDAY(3), WEDNESDAY(5), THURSDAY(2), FRIDAY(1), SATURDAY(6), SUNDAY(4);

    Day(int v) {
        this.dayValue = v;
    }

    int dayValue;

    public int getDayValue() {
        return dayValue;
    }
}
```

Then there's no branching involved.

```
public static int getValue(Day day){
    return day.getDayValue();
}
```

Comment: Actually, there’s more to it than JIT optimization.